# Google map not complete load in bootstrap 3.0 modal

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I add jquery location picker into content box of bootstrap modal 3. Like This :

HTML:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary">Launch modal</a>

    <div class="modal" id="myModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                     <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">Location:
                    <input type="text" id="us2-address" style="width: 200px" />Radius:
                    <input type="text" id="us2-radius" />
                    <div id="us2" style="height: 400px;"></div>Lat.:
                    <input type="text" id="us2-lat" />Long.:
                    <input type="text" id="us2-lon" />
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer"> <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Close</a>
     <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="save-changes">Save changes</a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now, when load google map`(click in launch modal)` not load completed and I see Part of it.

**NOTE** : if resize window of browser map loaded.

See Pic :

[image]

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/Lzv7w/3/

How to fix this ?!

Comment: I'd try using this code to generate: http://www.bootply.com/solrac/106707

Comment: Where is `#myDiv` before you append it to the modal body?

Comment: @Blazemonger: I remove `#myDiv` from JS But Not Fix !! http://jsfiddle.net/Lzv7w/5/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way :

You init the map, the first time you show the modal...

**Fiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/Lzv7w/8/

**Js** :

```
var stillPresent = false;
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
        if(stillPresent == false){
               $('#us2').locationpicker({
            location: {
                latitude: 46.15242437752303,
                longitude: 2.7470703125
            },
            radius: 300,
            inputBinding: {
                latitudeInput: $('#us2-lat'),
                longitudeInput: $('#us2-lon'),
                radiusInput: $('#us2-radius'),
                locationNameInput: $('#us2-address')
            }
        });
         stillPresent = true;
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem but loading the map inside a tab, to fix the problem you must call `.locationpicker` when you click on tab, in my case here the solution :

```
$( "#map_container" ).click(function() {
     $('#us3').locationpicker({
         location: {latitude: 35.770681, longitude: 10.828099},
         radius: 300,
         inputBinding: {
             latitudeInput: $('#us3-lat'),
             longitudeInput: $('#us3-lon'),
             radiusInput: $('#us3-radius'),
             locationNameInput: $('#us3-address')
         },
         enableAutocomplete: true,
         onchanged: function (currentLocation, radius, isMarkerDropped) {
         }
     });
});
```