# Bootstrap tabs and google maps not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps, tabs

Right, i have 2 tabs and inside there i have 2 maps. When i load the page the first map is fine, but when i click on the other tab, the map is not loading all.

After reading online, i tried this but it wont work. Here is the js

```
    function initialize( )
    {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.386199,0.189108);
        var latlng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(51.133802,-0.179009);
        var myOptions =
        {
            zoom: 13,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var myOptions2 =
        {
            zoom: 13,
            center: latlng2,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };


        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

        var map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas_2"), myOptions2);

        var image = 'images/marker.png';

        var myMarker = new google.maps.Marker(
        {
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
            title:"Head Office"
       });

        var myMarker2 = new google.maps.Marker(
        {
            position: latlng2,
            map: map2,
            title:"Crawley & Accounts Office"
        });

    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#tablist a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).tab('show');
  resetMap(map);
});
function resetMap(m) {
    x = m.getZoom();
    c = m.getCenter();
    google.maps.event.trigger(m, 'resize');
    m.setZoom(x);
    m.setCenter(c);
}
});
```

Comment: I think it's the same problem as here http://stackoverflow.com/q/24679156/2454790 , except it's a modal not a tab... The answer is almost the same except you have to fire the 'shown.bs.tab' event.... Good luck

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried re-initializing the map in your new tab when it opens?

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
      $('#tablist a').click(function(e) {    
        e.preventDefault();   
        $(this).tab('show');  
        initialize();  //Initialize map function
        resetMap(map);
      });
```

you must re-initialize the map in the new tab that was previously hidden and displayd after you clicked on #tablist.

Answer (score 0):

try re-initializing the map

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {

            initialize();

        });
```